# How to allow Jenkins to use usr/bin/security?

Tags: ios, macos, jenkins, permissions

I'm building an iPhone app with Jenkins so at some point it needs to use `/usr/bin/security`. Unfortunately Jenkins can't find that command.

Here's the console log excerpt:

`[workspace] $ /usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v FATAL: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/security" (in directory "/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obfuscated iOS/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/security" (in directory "/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Obfuscated iOS/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory`

Something like this typically means there is a permissions issue, so I have tried `sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/security` but the build yields the same result.

Furthermore, when I try `/usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v` from terminal it works just fine.

How do I get Jenkins to be able to use this tool and any other iOS tools it might need?

### More info:

The odd part is that other iOS related tools like `/usr/bin/xcodebuild` and `/usr/bin/agvtool` work fine as seen below:

`[workspace] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 6.4
Build version 6E35b
Fetching marketing version number (CFBundleShortVersionString) from project.
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/agvtool mvers -terse1
Found marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString): 4.0.0.
Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) found in project configuration: 4.0.0.
Fetching technical version number (CFBundleVersion) from project.
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/agvtool vers -terse`

### More on permissions:

`ls -le` yields

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel    224032 Aug  1 20:43 security
```

This looks normal to me when compared to other tools in the same directory like xcodebuild.

### Jenkins PATH

I checked the Jenkins System Configuration page and it lists this for PATH:
`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

### Running in a build step works!

If I create a new job with only a build step with the command, `/usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v`, then it runs fine.

This suggests that internally the command is being run by another process.

Comment: Hello, xcode-plugin maintainer here. We usually use the issue tracker to report these issues.

As for your problem, I don't see any obvious issue. error=2 is usually when the system cannot find the file, because of permissions, broken link, or wrong target slave, etc.

Which version of jenkins are you running ?

Comment: Jenkins 1.573. I did a lot of checking of permissions above but it does sound like something like that. It's not a symbolic link and it's a single machine. My apologies for leading you here but I couldn't figure out how to sign in to log an issue in JIRA.

Comment: Just upgraded to 1.637 with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was occurring because of the value used in "Build output directory":

[image]

Removing `${WORKSPACE}` resolved the issue with calling /usr/bin/security.